# Add characters on each side of a block

Tags: fill-column

I want to write a function which equally add "-" character on each sides of bold text. The future line should be no longer then `fill-column`

Input:

```
- <1900-01-01 Mon> *XX century* <1999-12-31 Fri>
```

Output:

```
- <1900-01-01 Mon> --------------- *XX century* --------------- <1999-12-31 Fri>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with a combination of `re-search-forward` and `replace-match` on subgroups (in this case the spaces just before and after <kbd>*</kbd>. You can simplify the regular expression if you don't want match the timestamps.

```
(defun add-dashes-to-line ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (when (re-search-forward (rx "-" space
                                 "<" (1+ (not (in ">"))) ">"
                                 (group space)
                                 "*" (1+ (not (in "*"))) "*"
                                 (group space)
                                 "<" (1+ (not (in ">"))) ">")
                             (point-at-eol) t 1)
      (let* ((line-length (- fill-column (- (point-at-eol) (point-at-bol))))
            (replacement (concat " "
                                 (make-string (/ line-length 2) ?-)
                                 " ")))
        (replace-match replacement  nil t nil 1)
        (replace-match replacement  nil t nil 2)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am very much an elisp beginner. I'm sure there's a better way than this, but took the question as a bit of a personal challenge.

Here's my crack at it. I don't think the 'if' statement is working... It's meant to add an extra "-" if there's an odd number needed. I've run out of time however so can't fix it.

```
(defun my-pack-line ()
  (interactive)
  ; Determine the blank spaces between end of line and fill-column value
  (setq to-fill (- fill-column (progn (end-of-line) (current-column))))

  ; Put point to right of first timestamp
  (move-to-column 18)

  ; Insert half of dashes here
  (setq n-dashes (/ to-fill 2))
  (insert " ")
  (setq xx 1)
  (while (< xx n-dashes)
    (insert "-")
    (setq xx (1+ xx)))

  ; Go to start of second timestamp
  (end-of-line)
  (setq xx 1)
  (while (< xx 18)
    (left-char)
    (setq xx (1+ xx)))

  ; Insert remaining dashes
  (if (oddp to-fill)
      (setq xx 1)
      (setq xx 0))
  (insert " ")
  (setq xx 1)
  (while (< xx n-dashes)
    (insert "-")
    (setq xx (1+ xx))))
```

Comment: James thank you from your answer but I went other way :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason rpluim's answer not working all the time and I've noticed I need some calculation for `replacement` variable (see the function below).

Current working function with satisfies my needs is:

```
(defun equal-re-hl-line ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((text (thing-at-point 'line t))
         (line-ln (- fill-column (- (point-at-eol) (point-at-bol))))
         (hzl-left (concat " " (make-string (/ (- line-ln 3) 2) ?-) " *"))
         (hzl-right (concat "* " (make-string (/ (- line-ln 3) 2) ?-) " ")))
    (delete-region (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))
    (insert (with-temp-buffer
              (insert (replace-regexp-in-string "\s\\*" hzl-left (replace-regexp-in-string "\\*\s" hzl-right text)))
              (buffer-string)))))
```

**TODO**

- how to add optional regex marker not just "*"
- function adding an extra new line, how to avoid it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what was going wrong?